# How can I get an email in a specific outlook inbox by date?

Tags: python

How can I, instead of get last, provide a date for it to search for?
And if it does not find it get me the previous date

```
get_path = 'C:\\Users\...'
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
archiveFolder = inbox.Folders.Item("A")
archiveFolder1 = archiveFolder.Folders.Item("A")
messages = archiveFolder1.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
```

Comment: What is that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use pywin32 library something like:
Here is a link of all methods and properties you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem

And I'm not sure to understand what you mean by previous date... But you will find below an exemple to find message received yesterday:

```
import datetime
get_path = 'C:\\Users\...'
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
archiveFolder = inbox.Folders.Item("A")
archiveFolder1 = archiveFolder.Folders.Item("A")
messages = archiveFolder1.Items
for message in messages:
    if message.ReceivedTime.date==datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=1):
         #do what you Want with message
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I want to search for a date. For instance in folder A find the email of 12-02-2020